# JPA mapping sports game with two @OneToOne relations

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, one-to-one

I have the following hierarchy for a football match.

```
@Entity
public class Match {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    protected Integer id;

    @Column(name = "home_team_id")
    private int homeTeamId;

    @Column(name = "away_team_id")
    private int awayTeamId;

    private TeamScore homeScore;

    private TeamScore awayScore;
}

@Entity(name = "team_score")
public class TeamScore  {
    @EmbeddedId
    protected TeamScoreId id;

    private List<Goal> goals;
}

@Embeddable
public class TeamScoreId {
    @Column(name = "match_id")
    private Integer matchId;

    @Column(name = "team_id") 
    private int teamId;
}
```

And I have a problem with mapping homeScore and awayScore in Match with TeamScore entity. 
The first concern is whether two @OneToOne relations should be here. And how should they be configured? 
The second one relates to matchId in TeamScoreId. How this mapping can be performed?

Answer (score 0):

> The first concern is whether two @OneToOne relations should be here. And how should they be configured?

Yes we should have one to one configured for TeamScores.

> The second one relates to matchId in TeamScoreId. How this mapping can be performed?
> That mapping performed as one to one without the annotation.

Example data saved in java code like below

```java
session.persist(Match.builder()
        .homeTeamId(1)
        .awayTeamId(2)
        .awayScore(TeamScore.builder()
                .id(TeamScoreId.builder()
                        .matchId(1)
                        .teamId(1)
                        .build())
                .goals(List.of(Goal.builder()
                        .score(1)
                        .build()))
                .build())
        .homeScore(TeamScore.builder()
                .id(TeamScoreId.builder()
                        .matchId(2)
                        .teamId(2)
                        .build())
                .goals(List.of(Goal.builder()
                        .score(2)
                        .build()))
                .build())
        .build());
```

It generates the team score data like below
[image: h2 db explorer]

I changed the classes like below

```java
@Entity
@Data
@Builder
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
public class Match {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    protected Integer id;

    @Column(name = "home_team_id")
    private int homeTeamId;

    @Column(name = "away_team_id")
    private int awayTeamId;

    @OneToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    private TeamScore homeScore;
    @OneToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    private TeamScore awayScore;
}
```

```java
@Entity
@Data
@Builder
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
public class Goal implements Serializable {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private Long id;
    private int score;
    @CreationTimestamp
    Instant createDate;
}
```

```java
@Entity(name = "team_score")
@Builder
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
public class TeamScore implements Serializable {
    @EmbeddedId
    protected TeamScoreId id;
    @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    private List<Goal> goals;
}
```

```java
@Embeddable
@Builder
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
public class TeamScoreId implements Serializable {
    @Column(name = "match_id")
    private Integer matchId;
    @Column(name = "team_id")
    private int teamId;
}
```

Find full working example [here](https://github.com/ozkanpakdil/java-examlpes/tree/master/jpa-onetoone).